# Multiple tasks running same method

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a grid with multiple SQL queries, which I want users to allow to execute when they double click on a row in the grid.  I want a user to be able to run multiple queries at the same time.

I have a small **Form** with a progress bar and timer for each query. The Form is displayed when a query is run and shows complete after the query has finished.

Below is my code, it seems that the method returning the data is blocking. I haven't worked with sync/threads/tasks before

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationTokenHook hook = new CancellationTokenHook(cts);
    CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
    //this.waitFormActivator.ShowWaitForm(true, true);
    //this.waitFormActivator.SetWaitFormObject(hook);
    Exception exception = null;
    try
    {

      progressControl.Start();

      Task<Dataset> t = Test(command.CommandText, token, saveFileDialog1.FileName);

      var result = await t;

      progressControl.Stop(); 

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        //success = false;
        exception = ex;
        //return null;
     }                               
 }
```

I would like the queries to run independently of each other, however currently the next query is waiting for the previous one to finish.

Comment: Would you believe it if i told you, `await` actually waits for the task to finish. Please do some google searches on `Task.WhenAll` it will point you in the right direction

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "blocking"? Please explain **exactly** the behavior you're seeing and/or the behavior you want.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "asynchronous" and "concurrent". The code you have written is asychronous, but you want it to be concurrent.

Comment: I would like to know when a specific task finishes, but I don't want the other tasks to be held up by an already task that is executing. 
I will look into concurrent.  Thanks

Comment: Does this queries select values in the same tables? Maybe the problem isn't in the code but the DBMS that locks tables when are you selecting them. If you're writing your own queries without any ORM on SQL Server, try to use SELECT <table> with(NOLOCK) and check if it works.

Comment: @TheGeneral `await` is waiting before executing the rest of the code (after await) inside the event handler. It does not prevent the user from invoking other handlers concurrently, or the same handler twice.

Comment: `it seems that the method returning the data is blocking` could be. Why not post the code here so we can figure it out?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am not really sure of what your point is exactly, I'm pretty sure you are not trying to teach me abiut the async and await pattern or tasks. The point is await and async does not equate to parrellel code

Comment: @TheGeneral the OP has a difficulty achieving concurrency, and your comment ❝await actually waits for the task to finish❞ could be interpreted like "await prevents other concurrent operations". In other words attributing OP's difficulties to `await`. Your answers and comments are generally helpful, educational and well written, but I find this particular one a bit misleading to be honest.

Comment: @nvoigt Thank you, the 3rd party library I used to run the sql command had a lock command in, hence making each task wait for the previous one to finish. I have changed the method to just use System.Data.SqlClient and works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is suppose to answer to your question

```
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        tasks.Add(new Task(() => { action1 }));
        tasks.Add(new Task(() => { action2 }));
        tasks.Add(new Task(() => { action3 }));
        tasks.Add(new Task(() => { action4 }));

        Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

In your context it's suppose to be like that :

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationTokenHook hook = new CancellationTokenHook(cts);
    CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
    his.waitFormActivator.ShowWaitForm(true, true);
    his.waitFormActivator.SetWaitFormObject(hook);
    eption exception = null;
    try
    {

      progressControl.Start();
      List<Task<Dataset>> tasks = new List<Task<DataSert>>();

      Task<Dataset> t1 = Test(command.CommandText, token, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
      Task<Dataset> t2 = Test(command.CommandText, token, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
      Task<Dataset> t3 = Test(command.CommandText, token, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
      Task<Dataset> t4 = Test(command.CommandText, token, saveFileDialog1.FileName);

      tasks.Add(t1);
      tasks.Add(t2);
      tasks.Add(t3);
      tasks.Add(t4);

      var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

      progressControl.Stop(); 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //success = false;
        exception = ex;
        //return null;
    }                               
}
```